# Database design and structure for product variants

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, relational-database, e-commerce

I have a variants for products for example Variant: Size, it has values like Small, Medium, Large. Then Color, values: Red, Orange, blue. Then Material, values: Cotton, Lawn. So I want a database design that have same price, sku for one variant e.g Small Red Cotton have same price and sku and this will repeat for others with different prices.

Comment: This post doesn't really show any effort or research on your part. What have you tried and found to not work?

Comment: I have tried but unable to make a design that have one price and sku per variant.

Comment: You need to provide more background info about how this information gets used as well as what are your thoughts about different designs.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to have a **Product** table, with three fields (ID, Price, SKU) as well as three foreign keys to lookup tables for size, colour and material.

However, it all depends on what other requirements you have, and what this is all going to be used for. If this isn't a stand-alone structure, it is very likely that the obvious solution is not the best one.